# how to insert filter type lookup value for a field in test class

Tags: unit-test, lookup-filter

this is my test class

```
@isTest
private class oerClass_Test {
    static testMethod void unitTest() {
        //Account Insert
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.name = 'test';
        insert acc;
      ;
        objpm.CloseDate = 6 / 16 / 2016;
        objpm.Application_Detail__c = 'test';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookup Filter value should match your test record.

Create a Product Type record with field Is Disable = False.

Then create a Product Model record. Use newly created Product Type record while creating a Product Model record.

Use newly created Product Model record on Opportunity.

This will set your lookup filter criteria.

Hope this helps :)